# Postgres VACUUM , REINDEX, ANALYSE

Tags: postgresql, optimization, maintenance

How do I know if I need to run any of VACUUM, REINDEX, ANALYSE? Because I don't want to run this every day even if it is not needed.

For example, is it a good option to run all of above after 100 updates?

Is there some query that will tell me "**Yes**, you need to run Vacuum on table xyz"? Something like self analysis for performance optimization.

Comment: https://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Introduction_to_VACUUM,_ANALYZE,_EXPLAIN,_and_COUNT